# Relation between hyperbolic numbers and hyperbolic functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, trigonometry, idempotents, split-complex-numbers

Is there any relation between the hyperbolic (split-complex) numbers and hyperbolic trig functions? Or are they just named similarly by accident?

Comment: Would [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number#Geometry) paragraph answer your question ?

Comment: It does if $z=|z|e^{j \theta}$ for any split-complex $z$, analogous to the complex numbers.  This is probably the case, but wikipedia doesn't explicitly say so.